# A separate menu for each page - Qt and Android

Tags: android, qt

I'm using `ApplicationWindow` and `StackView` to provide multiple pages to a user.

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 1.0

ApplicationWindow
{
    menuBar: MenuBar {
        Menu {
            title: qsTr("Menu")
            MenuItem
            {
                text: qsTr("Enter page")
                onTriggered: stackView.push("qrc:/qml/SecondPage.qml")
            }
            MenuItem
            {
                text: qsTr("Base screen option")
                onTriggered: /**/
            }
        }
    }

    StackView
    {
        id: stackView
        anchors.fill: parent
        focus: true

        initialItem: FirstPage {}
    }
}
```

When `SecondPage` is pushed to the stackView, the global menu is still displayed. I tried making `StackView` the top element and pushing `ApplicationWindow` there, but the `StackView` component needs a parent.

Is there any way to implement a page-specific menu?

Comment: I tried using states, but this doesn't work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Try and use properties in the ApplicationWindow to specify what text to show. Then these properties can be set in the pages in the stack view.

```
ApplicationWindow {
    id: rootWindow
    width: 360
    height: 360
    visible: true

    property string option1Text: "Enter page"
    property string option2Text: "Base screen option"

    menuBar: MenuBar {
        Menu {
            title: qsTr("Menu")
            MenuItem
            {
                id: option1TextItem
                text: qsTr(option1Text)
                onTriggered: stackView.push("qrc:/qml/SecondPage.qml")
            }
            MenuItem
            {
                id: option2TextItem
                text: qsTr(option2Text)
                onTriggered: console.log("Triggered option 2")
            }
        }
    }

    StackView
    {
        id: stackView
        anchors.fill: parent
        focus: true

        initialItem: FirstPage {}
    }
}
```

FirstPage:

```
Rectangle {
    anchors.fill: parent

    Component.onCompleted: {
        rootWindow.option1Text = "First Page"
        rootWindow.option2Text = "First Page Option"
    }
}
```